# Java contextLookup (LogManager error type mismatch)

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I have trouble with type mismatch in java. I have this lines of code:

```
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public abstract class Agent implements RemoteAgent {

  protected AID aid;

  private LogManager logManager;
  private AgentManager agentManager;
  private MessagesManager messageManager;

  .
  .
  .

  protected AgentManager getAgentManager() {
    if (agentManager == null) {
        agentManager = ManagerFactory.getAgentManager();
    }

    return agentManager;
  }

  protected MessagesManager getMessageManager() {
    if (messageManager == null) {
        messageManager = ManagerFactory.getMessagesManager();
    }

    return messageManager;
  }

  protected LogManager getLogManager() {
    if (logManager == null) {
        logManager = ManagerFactory.getLogManager();
    }

    return logManager;
  }
}
```

I give me error in this line :

```
logManager = ManagerFactory.getLogManager();
```

I did the same for LogManager as for MessagesManager and AgentManager but LogManager show this error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from LogRemote to LogManager

Here is my other class files which is part of this code:

https://github.com/MiselAdemi/agents/blob/agent-works/src/main/java/agents/environment/util/factory/ManagerFactory.java

https://github.com/MiselAdemi/agents/tree/agent-works/src/main/java/agents/environment/util/log

Can somebody tell me what is different in LogManager from MessagesManager and AgentManager?

Comment: could you supply all of the import statements for this class

Comment: https://github.com/MiselAdemi/agents/tree/agent-works/src/main/java/agents/environment/util/log Here is all classes used for Log, I cannot paste here all of code, so I must put link. @slambeth

Comment: We'll need the actual import statements you're using in your class, I'd wager, that you have the wrong "LogManager" class imported.

Comment: @slambeth you were right, I didn't see eclipse automatically imported wrong class, thank a lot